# Gem Install Bundle: You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory

Tags: theming

When I run drush omega-guard I get:

> There was a problem with your setup: Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

I have installed the Gem files through homebrew.

and when i try run `bundle install` again:

> Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory.

I read that you can use gulp. There is no gem folder in my sub theme so is this the correct way?

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XF_LaSfua8Y&index=10&list=PLLnpHn493BHH5nnK2dKE_42l1oXA6Tq6H][1]

I am using LevelUpTuts tutorial to set up my development environment.

I think the problem is that i can not run `gem install`; when I run `gem install bundle` I get the following error.

> You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory

How do I fix this?

Comment: Just FYI, I would think about installing Ruby via Homebrew and not mess around with OS X's built-in Ruby.

Comment: Is there a Gemfile anywhere in this project you are trying to build? Often with themes you have to descend into the theme directory to build dependencies like this.